# What does zend_db->select() provide over a direct pdo query?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Im looking over inherited code with the following (partial) class:

```
class Model_UserGenre extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {...    

$select = $this->select()->from(array('ug' => $this->_name), array('user_id'))
                     ->where('genre_id IN (?)', $genreID)
                                         ->orwhere('sub_genre_id IN(?)', $genreID)
                                         ->group(array('ug.user_id'));
      $result = $this->fetchAll($select);
      return $result;

...}
```

This is just a sample code. I am unfamiliar with Zend and have tried to read up on the zend db methods cursorily but to me it seems unnecessarily complicated vs just putting in the query string when I am not using a fully dynamic query

Does zend, especially in this case, present some kind of dynamic capability or efficiency that a direct mysqli or PDO query does not?

Thanks and sorry for the noobish question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query builder is just there as a usability layer on top of a PDO. It provides some convenient functionality a PDO does not, like dealing with `IN` statements. It is also there to implement the [adapter design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), where your database driver can be very easily swapped out.

Essentially, A PDO will still require you to write raw SQL whereas the query builder will do that for you. Any SQL generated by the query builder will be valid for any SQL adapter the query builder supports (eg. PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite).

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I guess I would rather write raw sql as its easier to read, but the ability to swap connectors could be extrememly valuable. Thanks!

Comment: @MagicLasso I used to think the same way, but a little bit of smart indentation and experience/exposure makes the query builder syntax look pretty neat & easy to read.

Comment: Do you have a good go to reference for the zend framework, I am honstly having a bear of a time find a reference to the parameters for these methods (ill stop being lazy and dig in he code itself but a quicker reference would be nice)

Comment: I use PHP Storm as an IDE, and I generally discover syntax by following through to the definitions and looking at the code of the framework. Aside from that, the [Zend Framework docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html) aren't completely terrible